# Javascript regex get word but exclude from comment blocks

Tags: javascript, regex

Let say I have the following inside a file

```
<button aria-label="<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?>">

// JText

/**
 * Comment block
 * ------------------
 * @param   JText
 *
 */
```

What I'm trying to do is match the word `JText` but only if it's **not** inside an inline comment or comment block.

So in the example above, only the first instance should be returned.

So far I've got the following:

```
^\s*(?=\S)(?!\/\*\*)(?!\/\/)(?!\*).*(\\?)JText
```

which does positive look aheads for `/**`,`*/` and `//`, however when testing, this, it returns everything up to and including JText:

```
<button aria-label="<?php echo JText
```

Here is a working example of what I have so far:

https://regex101.com/r/voOvGv/1/

So how can I return only the string `JText`? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need a parser for that. Imagine you have `var s = "bad string /*here";` and then it will be next to impossible to know if the comment started within a string literal or not. You would need to account for that, too, and eventually, you will write the language parser, that should already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good point about the parser, but if you're willing to risk it, just make the text a group:

```
^\s*(?=\S)(?!\/\*\*)(?!\/\/)(?!\*).*(\\?)(JText)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WkrPxk/1

Comment: I don't see any other way if you are doing regexps. The `[0]` element is always the full match which contains everything before `JText`, so you need to add some capturing groups to clarify the match.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Nearly there with your code but the optional backslash before  `JText` isn't being included in the match

Comment: Finally got it working by replacing `.*` with `(.*?)`